# Why do I need to specify a timestamp server when using SignTool for code signing?

Tags: timestamp, code-signing

Timestamp is optional parameter, so please can anybody to explain difference between timestamped exe-file and not timestamped? What happens if I skip this option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you skip the timestamp option, then when your certificate expires the exe will no longer have a valid certificate on it.  If you use a timestamp server then the exe will always have a valid certificate.