# What happens when a timestamp server is not available anymore?

Tags: timestamp, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

if I want to digitally sign my code with a timestamp so that it's still trusted even if the certificate expired, will the code still be trusted if the timestamp server I used doesn't exist anymore?

In other words: 
Is a connection to the timestamping server required during verification before running the application?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533660/why-do-i-need-to-specify-a-timestamp-server-when-using-signtool-for-code-signing?rq=1

Comment: To be precise, I don't need to connect to the timestamp server while verifying the certificate at runtime, am I correct? 
Can you name a resource where this is described?